# Using deluge-console direct terminal

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

Is there a way to pipe deluge-console commands directly on the terminal?

I wanted to perform something:
`deluge-console; add torrent-file-url.torrent`

I know that when you run `deluge-console` you're being redirected to another screen on top of your regular terminal. I wanted to wrap this in a bash script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `deluge-console` man page:

> You can pass console commands directly from the command line and run 
>   multiple  commands  by separating them with a semi-colon (;).

```
deluge-console add torrent-file-url.torrent
deluge-console add torrent-file-url.torrent; info torrent_id
```

To prevent issues with spaces in filenames use quotes around the entire command string e.g.

```
deluge-console "add torrent-file-url.torrent; info torrent_id"
```